# Query for daily before 11am with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time, str-to-date

I have a **datetime** field and want to get all entries before 11am. It is for an online store where you can order until 11:00am and it will be shipped the same day.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tablename 
WHERE (order.date_added < STR_TO_DATE(YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY()'%Y %d,%M'), '11:00:00')
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to assemble this statement.

Comment: What is `filed` and I don't see any operation involving `11:00:00`.

Comment: filed.date_added < date(CURDATE()) + interval 11 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want orders before 11:00 a.m. *today*, you can use:

```
where o.date_added >= curdate() and
      time(o.date_added) < '11:00:00'
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer exactly what I was looking for. now I can add 5 more minutes so everyone is satisfied and gets his order.
Thanks for your help.
`SELECT * FROM order WHERE order.date_added >= curdate() and time(order.date_added) < '11:05:00'`

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the currentday at 11 o'clock

```
CurDATE() + INTERVAL  11 HOUR
```

And the query selects all orders between yesterday 11 and today eleven.

you should add also criteria to exclude all orders that are already made

> ```
> CREATE tABLe orders (date_added DATETIME)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders VALUES (NOW() -INTERVAL 10 HOUR)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM orders 
> WHERE orders.date_added BETWEEN (CurDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL  11 HOUR AND  CurDATE() + INTERVAL  11 HOUR
> ```
>
> ```
> | date_added          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2021-07-08 06:40:50 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CurDATE() + INTERVAL  11 HOUR
> ```
>
> ```
> | CurDATE() + INTERVAL  11 HOUR |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | 2021-07-08 11:00:00           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1150119ce4b04d5c532aab1b9a70a47)*